# Why do profilers fail to get information from my program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

I am trying to profile a C++ program but whenever I run a profiler I get no information even though the debug information works as I can run a debugger on it.

I tried using AMD uProf, Very Sleepy and Visual Studio but all of them give me no information. No functions get detected.

The program is compiled using clang-cl and runs for only a few milliseconds.

Comment: Binary built without debug symbols perhaps?

Comment: How do you build your program, with what options and flags? How do you run your program? How do you attempt to *profile* the program?

Comment: @Some programmer dude I built it with debug information and optimization off, I also have fast floating point math and sse 4.1 enabled. To profile I just run the profiler with the  program executable and the arguments. In Visual Studio I open it with devenv like I would if I was debugging and click Debug -> Performance Profiler. I also tried building with optimization and without debug information but neither helped

Comment: @Yksisarvinen didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Windows Defender was messing with somethings, it has caused me some trouble in the past as well. Disabling it and rebooting seems to have fixed the problem. Also due to the program having such a short execution time most profilers aren't able to get enough samples